# Is it possible to remove a row depends on a particular value in AngularJs ui grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display a list of data using ui grid. In that grid I want to filter some rows depends on the the value.

```
var app = angular.module('uigrid', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27, visible: "false"},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29, visible: "false"},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableRowSelection: true,
  enableSelectAll: true,
  multiSelect: true,
  enableColumnMenus: false,
  enableFiltering: true,
  rowHeight: 40,
  data : 'myData',
  columnDefs: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    },
    {
      name: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    },]
  };
}]);
```

In this list I don't want to display two rows with that property visible: "false"? Which is the best way to remove that rows?
I have created the grid [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vimalv86/ysmg1qkt/652/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in your `$scope.gridOptions` to show/hide rows

```
appScopeProvider: {
  showRow: function(row) {
    return row.visible !== 'false';
  }
},
```

Here is the working [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/etRNAIv9BK6ODRp5AEHD?p=preview).